# Appium installation on Windows 7

Tags: appium

I have tried to install Appium on Windows 7 for automated testing of Android mobile apps. but it failed.

Can you please let me know, if Appium could be installed on Windows 7 ?
If yes, can you please give any link or reference where I can find and follow the installation steps on Windows 7.

Comment: What have you tried? Any error logs? You can simple download the windows installer from [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.2.6) and run it.

Comment: Hello lalongooo, I followed your instruction and tried again. Went to the site, https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.2.6 (as you mentioned the link as 'here') and downloaded the appium-desktop-Setup-1.2.6.exe and started installation. It does nothing, and eventually the downloaded software package also disappeared from my computer. Strange ! BTW, I am the admin of my computer.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I found the issue. The corporate antivirus (AV) blocked me to install the software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can install Appium on Windows 7.
All you need is to install Appium for Windows along with android-sdk and Genymotion(for running your tests on simulators). You however wont be run your tests on ios as it requires xcode which is not present on Windows.

After you have installed Appium(via .exe or GUI) you'll have a folder created via name Appium (by default in Program Files(x86).

To start your appium server, simple type appium &.
In order to initialize Node/Grid, go to the path where the Appium folder is created and traverse to Appium\node_modules\appium\bin. Initialize your json config using node appium --nodeconfig commands.

You can download Appium for Windows directly from Appium's of cial website (http://appium.io/), or you can clone Appium from https://github.com/ appium/appium.git.
Just to ensure that we are ready to start with the Appium server, enter the following command on the Command Prompt:
node Appium-doctor

You don't need to download Node; you can get it from the Appium bundle. To run the Node commands, you need to set the path for Node (for example, C:\ AppiumForWindows). Before running the command, set the directory as C:\ AppiumForWindows\node_modules\appium\bin.

Comment: Hello Priyanka: I am wondering where to get the Appium package for Windows 7 ? I went here: http://appium.io/downloads.html and at the bottom of that page there is a link under the title: 'Appium Desktop Apps' but it shows no install package for Windows. Please help me to find the Appium package.

Comment: In the Downloads section of the latest release, you will find different packages for Windows, Mac, Linux etc. For the Windows version, download the following .exe - appium-desktop-Setup-1.2.6.exe

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I found the issue. The corporate antivirus (AV) blocked me to install the software.